# 'int' object is not subscriptable error in 3d array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access individual values from a 3D matrix of shape (7,4,6) layer by layer.I want to access value from one (row X column) for all 7 layers and compare them but get an error in the accessing values part. Also I am able to print them properly in the order required. The code I have written is:

```
array = [[[-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99,   1],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99,   1]],

   [[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]],

   [[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]],

   [[  1,   1,   1,   1, -99, -99],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1, -99, -99],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1, -99, -99],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1, -99]],

   [[  0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]],

   [[-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99]],

   [[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
    [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1],
    [  0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]]]
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,6):
        for k in range(0,7):
            a = array([k][i][j])
            if (a == 0 and b == 0):
                NN += 1
            elif (a == 0 and b == 1):
                RN += 1
            elif (a == 1 and b == 0):
                NR += 1
            elif (a == 1 and b == 1):
                RR += 1
            else:
                exit
            b = a
```

RR, NN, NR and RN and b are declared 0 a=in initial state
but I get

> TypeError:'int' object is not subscriptable

in the last line. I saw it through in net and it said I have to convert it into string to operate with it. Can someone explain it to me why we have to do so and how?

Comment: Please provide a REAL [mcve].

Comment: Please provide the array declaration (as @brunodesthuilliers requested)

Comment: If `array` is a 3D Numpy array (and if it is, you shouldn't call it `array`), then the correct indexing would be `a = arr[k][i][j]`

Comment: @ bruno i have edited the code and given you the full code i am working with.

Comment: @ david the same array([k][i][j]) works when i give a print statement without any error. Can u clarify as to why?

Comment: Are you sure? You simply don't address an array with the indices in parentheses. I've just tried your code and it does appear to work with `a = array[k][i][j]`

Comment: @david thanks. Now im able to access the values. But can u explain why i was able to access without brackets in this case while with print statement it wasnt a problem?

Comment: It *is* a problem in a print statement. I have just tested this and get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`, same as your error above.

Comment: ohh ok thanks david for your help:)